# Getting ServiceFault response from server

Tags: opc-ua

- In OPCUA, Initially server responding properly to all
  CreateMonitoredItemRequest with  CreateMonitoredItemResponse. After
  sometime, server sending Service Fault response to
  CreateMonitoredItemRequest.
- Using One tool I am sending CreateMonitoredItemRequest to server
  after that server respond with server fault.

Can anyone tell what is the meaning of service Fault? I am quite new to OPCUA protocol.

Answer (score 0):

A `ServiceFault` response contains a `StatusCode` that should indicate the reason for failure.